# How to use SetConsoleTextAttribute C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, x86, console-application

I have searched countless forums and websites but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to use *SetConsoleTextAttribute* but it only affects the text. How can I affect the whole screen like the command `color 1f` would? My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle("C++ CALCULATOR"); // Title of window
    int x; // Decision
    int a; // First Number
    int b; // Second Number
    int c; // Answer
    HANDLE Con;
    Con = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Con, BACKGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED);
    cout << "CALCULATOR" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1:ADDITION" << endl << "2:SUBTRACTION" << endl << "3:MULTIPLICATION";
    cout << endl << "4:DIVISION" << endl << "5:EXIT" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 1: // Addition code
            cout << endl << "ADDITION" << endl << "FIRST NUMBER:";
            cin >> a;
            cout << endl << "SECOND NUMBER:";
            cin >> b;
            c = a + b;
            cout << endl << "ANSWER:" << c;
            break;
        case 2: // Subtraction code
            cout << endl << "SUBTRACTION" << endl << "FIRST NUMBER:";
            cin >> a;
            cout << endl << "SECOND NUMBER:";
            cin >> b;
            c = a - b;
            cout << endl << "ANSWER:" << c;
            break;
        case 3: // Multiplication code
            cout << endl << "MULTIPLICATION" << endl << "FIRST NUMBER:";
            cin >> a;
            cout << endl << "SECOND NUMBER:";
            cin >> b;
            c = a * b;
            cout << endl << "ANSWER:" << c;
            break;
        case 4: // Division code
            cout << endl << "DIVISION" << endl << "FIRST NUMBER:";
            cin >> a;
            cout << endl << "SECOND NUMBER:";
            cin >> b;
            c = a / b;
            cout << endl << "ANSWER:" << c;
            break;
        case 5: // Exit code
            return 0;


    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sure `SetConsoleTextAttribute` is not part o C++ language

Comment: Yeah like @Amadeus said it would be part of the console... Which console are you using?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Have you read the docs? [First link in Google search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: _"like color 1f would"_ ? That requires explanation. Are you referring to `POKE &H3d8, &H1f`? That's sooo 1986, and won't work unless you have authentic CGA/EGA emulation :)

Comment: OK so im writing a C++ program and im including windows.h people have said that using system("color 1f") would not be practical so im trying to use SetConsoleTextAttribute to change the color of the Command Prompt screen

Comment: The windows command "color 1f"

Comment: @Somperson99 Code should go into the post, not a pastebin. I don't see it making much of a difference here, but in general when people need to go over your code to understand the problem, Don't put required information off-site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution relies on these WinAPI functions and structures:

- [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171(v=vs.85).aspx) to get screen dimensions
- [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682662(v=vs.85).aspx) to fill screen with an attribute
- [CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to store screen information

The code is as follows:

```
HANDLE hCon;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiScreenInfo;
COORD coordStart = { 0, 0 };  // Screen coordinate for upper left
DWORD dwNumWritten = 0;       // Holds # of cells written to 
                              // by FillConsoleOutputAttribute
DWORD dwScrSize;
WORD  wAttributes = BACKGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;

hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// Get the screen buffer information including size and position of window
if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hCon, &csbiScreenInfo))
{
    // Put error handling here
    return 1;
}
// Calculate number of cells on screen from screen size
dwScrSize = csbiScreenInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.X * csbiScreenInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y;
// Fill the screen with the specified attribute
FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hCon, wAttributes, dwScrSize, coordStart, &dwNumWritten);
// Set attribute for newly written text
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hCon, wAttributes);
```

The inline comments should be enough to understand the basics of what is going with the supplied documentation links. We get the screen size with *GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo* and use that to determine the number of cells on the screen to update with a new attribute using *FillConsoleOutputAttribute* . We then use *SetConsoleTextAttribute* to ensure that all new text that gets printed matches the attribute we used to color the entire console screen.

For brevity I have left off the error check for the calls to *FillConsoleOutputAttribute* and *SetConsoleTextAttribute*. I put a stub for the error handling for *GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo* . I leave it as an exercise for the original poster to add appropriate error handling if they so choose.

Comment: Thanks very much i'm really new to C++ and this helped alot hope i didnt cause too much trouble with all of the miscommunication, and i'm new to stack overflow too i tried to put my code in and it looked like a jumbled mess thanks again

Comment: No problem at all, I cleaned up your question a bit. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

`SetConsoleTextAttribute` changes the attribute for new characters that you write to the console, but doesn't affect existing contents of the console.

If you want to change the attributes for existing characters already being displayed on the console, use [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687407.aspx) instead.

Comment: I would like it to effect the whole screen even where there is not text

Comment: @Somperson99: Let me put it this way: although I haven't disassembled it to check, it looks to me like `color xx` probably uses `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` (probably along with `SetConsoleTextAttribute`, so when you write more text, it shows up in the same color).